# How can I download a specific version of Visual Studio build tools?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

My 2017 build tools updated for a program that I maintain, and since the update my debugger has completely broken. I have uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio build tools multiple times with a number of different compilers, but nothing works.

The build tools version updated from `15.9.28307.2094` to `15.9.34601.69` and I cannot find anywhere to download this version of compiler. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ask Microsoft. You could start by filing a bug, since their update obviously broke the debugging.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks. have submitted on via the feedback hub.